# Keeping select item selected in php after submit in form

Tags: php, forms, select

How do i keep my select item selected via PHP? i did it the same way with radiobuttons and it worked. the only thing i changed was changed "checked" to "selected" as was recommended to me.

Here is my PHP:

```
if (empty($_POST["favFruit"])) {
    $favFruitErr = "You must select 1 or more";
  }
  else {
    $favFruit = $_POST["favFruit"];
  }
```

And here is my form:

```
<select class=favfruitwindow name="favFruit[]" size="4" multiple>
          <option <?php if (isset($favFruit) && $favFruit == "apple") echo "selected"; ?> value="apple">Apple</option>
          <option <?php if (isset($favFruit) && $favFruit == "banana") echo "selected"; ?> value="banana">Banana</option>
          <option <?php if (isset($favFruit) && $favFruit == "plum") echo "selected"; ?> value="plum">Plum</option>
          <option <?php if (isset($favFruit) && $favFruit == "pomegranate") echo "selected"; ?> value="pomegranate">Pomegranate</option>
          <option <?php if (isset($favFruit) && $favFruit == "strawberry") echo "selected"; ?> value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
          <option <?php if (isset($favFruit) && $favFruit == "watermelon") echo "selected"; ?> value="watermelon">Watermelon</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$favFruit` will be an array even when selecting a single option, and null when nothing is selected.

`print_r($_POST["favFruit"]);` will return `Array ( [0] => banana [1] => plum )`

You need for see if the item exists in the array and select based on that check.

```
<select class=favfruitwindow name="favFruit[]" size="4" multiple>
    <option <?php if (isset($favFruit) && in_array('apple', $favFruit)) echo "selected"; ?> value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($favFruit) && in_array('banana', $favFruit)) echo "selected"; ?> value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($favFruit) && in_array('plum', $favFruit)) echo "selected"; ?> value="plum">Plum</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($favFruit) && in_array('pomegranate', $favFruit)) echo "selected"; ?> value="pomegranate">Pomegranate</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($favFruit) && in_array('strawberry', $favFruit)) echo "selected"; ?> value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($favFruit) && in_array('watermelon', $favFruit)) echo "selected"; ?> value="watermelon">Watermelon</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Done, im sorry, new to so.